# How can I avoid magic strings for views' names and paths?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

If I call a controller or class anywhere in the project, I just use the namespace and filename:

```
string vc = nameof(MyProject.Controllers.MySillyController)
```

Great for refactoring if I rename `MySillyController` or move its namespace I'll get compile-time errors.

But I can't do the same thing for a view?

I have to string it:

```
string v = "~/Views/Info/Create.cshtml"
```

I found a question that refers to a helper:

```
string path = (helper.ViewDataContainer as WebPageBase).VirtualPath;
```

But there's not much context and I have no idea what this helper class actually is. Is it from a NuGet package, an old feature built-in, or what?

Comment: Can you explain where you're encountering this need? Aside from unit tests, I've never had to reference a controller or view outside of another controller or view where you have helper methods like `RedirectToAction()` or `Html.ActionLink()`.

Comment: It'd be for intellisense and compile-time highlights. If I change my `View` filename and/or folder structure, then I'd like anything referencing that path highlighted to show it doesn't exist.

Comment: In an MVC, don't call your view path directly (you are correct about refactoring issues) rather just call the controller / action method instead e.g. in a controller action method you could use: string view = /*some logic*/; return RedirectToRoute(new { action = view }); Don't know about the helper sorry.